# How to apply the Rewrite rules in php page links so that while rendering the page links get converted to rewrite rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-encoding

I am using the apche mod_rewrite applying some reules in .htaccess file,

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1.html [R,L,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

it works when it enter the url like

```
  http://localhost:6060/index.php
```

redirect to

```
 http://localhost:6060/index.html
```

However i need to convert the links in page like if links appeared in .php will be converted to .html extention

```
 <a href="index.php">home</a>
```

while rendering it will convert to

```
<a href="index.html">home</a>
```

Comment: What did you try, where did it jam ?

Comment: that is not possible with mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write PHP code at all.  Apache has a module for this called [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).

You'll haver to ensure your apache override settings allow use of this directive, and that you have loaded the following modules:

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule  headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module       modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadFile    /usr/lib/libxml2.so
LoadModule  xml2enc_module       modules/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module    modules/mod_proxy_html.so
```

Then, in your `.htaccess`, you just need to ensure that html proxy maps are enabled, and define your map in order for apache to change these links.  In your case:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On

#if you are using a new version of this module only... sets the Apache 
#to handle url's in href's, and ALSO links in scripts (like javascript), if you are
#changing all .html values these two directives are necesarry, but the second one
#especially adds overhead
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLInterp On
```

From here... it gets a bit tricky because aren't just changing the path, but also the extension.  To apply the action of changing the .php links to .html links, you use the `ProxyHTMLURLMap` directive, and it will need to look something like this:

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap .php .html $
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot apply `RewriteRule`s in reverse. A `RewriteRule` maps a URL to a file on disk,

1. the reverse is not always possible/obvious/unique and
2. Apache has nothing to do with what you do in PHP.

You need to write your own PHP code which generates URLs, which Apache can rewrite appropriately for incoming requests to those URLs. Typically a *(reverse) router* is used to do this. See [here](http://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router) for my humble implementation of one.